# External JS object to return link tag

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to extract a JS function in the body of my view (where it was working fine) and place it into an external js file as an object I can call a method on.

This is to use [Jottings JS email obfuscator](http://www.jottings.com/obfuscator/), currently I'm just outputting a hard-coded link tag.

My view:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/email-obfuscator.js">email.encrypt();</script>
```

My JS file:

```
var email = function()
{ 
    this.encrypt = function()
    {
        document.write('<a href="mailto:test@example.com">Support</a>');
    }
};
```

I'm not getting any JS errors, but neither am I getting any output, this is my first attempt at creating my own external JS object, any idea where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `encrypt` method is a public method of your class `email` - to use it, you need to create an instance of the email

```
var myEmail = new email();
myEmail.encrypt();
```

If you want to stick to the way you currently call your `encrypt` method, you need to make a static method out of it:

```
var email = function() {
  // do something
}

email.encrypt = function() {
  document.write('<a href="mailto:test@example.com">ELF Support</a>');
}
```

But whats best for you, depends on your current usage, You need to consider for yourself if you need multiple email instances and maybe encrypt different links or if it can stay static.

**Update**:
Almost forgot the important part: you need to separate the loading of the js file from the actual usage:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/email-obfuscator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var myEmail = new email(); 
  myEmail.encrypt();
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to be able to run a single method (passing a email parameter) on an existing (global) object: email.encrypt('test@example.com'); Thanks for the help, I assumed you could use the same script tag! I've gone for your 2nd example, what would you do where you have "// do something"? Is this where you declare private methods?

Comment: usually, you add instance and private variables inside the method - which is also the `constructor` of the class. But you can't access them in your `encrypt` method if you do it the static way.
[This Article](http://www.gediminasm.org/post/using-prototypal-inheritance-in-javascript) is a good start for understanding the usage of classes, inheritance, static and private methods, variables etc.